Duplicated answer after connection loss
I was editing my answer to this question when I lost my connection.
After restoring connection and submitting the update, I have got a new answer appearing like if I duplicated my answer instead of updating it.
I temporarily deleted the old version of the answer in order to "remove" the duplicate.
It probably needs a moderator intervention to effectively delete it instead of hiding it.
It may also be a bug in the update flow.

Your deletion is functionally the same as a moderator's ordinary deletion, aside from the name credited with the action in the logs. Users with the privilege to see deleted posts can see them whether they were deleted by the author or by a moderator or by community consensus. The only difference is if it gets marked as spam or rude or abusive, which your answer is clearly not. There is no further action necessary here. There's also no bug - there's no way Stack Overflow can do anything about your intermittent Internet connection. (Mine is pretty bad sometimes, too.)

@KarlKnechtel "there's no way Stack Overflow can do anything about your intermittent Internet connection." but intermittent connection shouldn't lead to double posting. Especially on an edit. Idempotency of a service is an important quality. Losing connection and reestablishing it should be normal things in a web context. An edit deciding to post an answer is, I'm fairly sure, undesirable and unintended.

@VLAZ in principle I agree; in practice I've seen analogous issues on all sorts of other websites. It doesn't seem to be an easy problem in general.

Just because other websites suffer from the same problem, doesn't invalidate the bug on this site. I'm honestly baffled at how an edit could possibly create a new post...

How did the site react when this happened? Did you have to reload the entire page and the edits were drawn from a cache, or did you get an ajax error and you could simply resubmit once the connection was back without having to do any kind of page reload?

@Gimby, I had a red pop up saying there is a problem when updating. I refreshed. Then I got no connection page from my browser. I reconnected. I clicked to back in my browser. I published. I imagine that using the unique ID of the answer in the updating flow may prevent recreating the answer.

@jlandercy "I clicked to back in my browser" - I should read that as that you clicked the browser's back button? The root of so many bugs, getting a page into an inconsistent state when people navigate back in page history :)

The "answer posted twice" bug has been reported several times before, see one report and another report. These two reports are older but it has also happened to me recently. Just clicking "back" isn't the only explanation, sometimes the system fails silently or has a bogus error message and if you click the submit button a second time the answer is posted twice. I wasn't able to find more recent bugs reports but I've seen them and they're out there. (It's difficult to reproduce but it happens)

A more recent bug report of the same issue and another similar issue involving use of the back button.
